# Wonderware archestra distributed application

Tags: distributed, wonderware

I'm using System Platform and deploying InTouch application.And I try to make distributed application. There is a server with InTouch Apps and a computer work station, that has to display InTouch Apps. How could I configure distributed application in  System Platform?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming existing installation

Create Instance of WinPlatform (Usually under /System in template Toolbox). Assign IP

Create Instance of ViewEngine (again in template Toolbox) Assign to newly created WinPlatfrom)

Create Instance of existing Intouch Application or create new instance of $InTouchViewApp.

Deploy WinPlatform, ViewEngine and Intouch Application.

Test Deployed application on target Platform.

Cheers!